# Error in using FeatureDetector OpenCv Android

Tags: opencv, android

Hy i would like to use opencV android for processing the image; i need to use the sift, so i write this code:

```
FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
```

However i've  got this error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector.create_0:(I)J
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: if you need SIFT, why are you using FAST?

Comment: Try `FeatureDetector::create(etc...)`, it's a static method

Comment: i read SIFT arent's supported so i used FAST. I can not write your code line. I'm developing in Android.

Comment: SIFT are supported, but they are in nonfree library (at least in C++).

Comment: You are linking opencv correctly, right? Every opencv part works except the featuredetector line? Imported `import org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector;` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is fired if you call feature detector before the opencv library has finished loading.

Putting

```
FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
```

inside of the loader callback will ensure that it only gets called after opencv has loaded. for example:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: //opencv is loaded!
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully"); 
                mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST); //feature detector goes here!
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};
```